# Contact form default value validation

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a contact form which was provided free on the web. Fingers crossed it's brilliant, however for forms where I've got a default value such as "Full Name" I'm not sure how to get it to validate in JS and PHP for those fields.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" onfocus="if(this.value=='Full Name') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Full Name';" value="Full Name" />
```

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        contactname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        telephone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 11
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages: {
        contactname: {
            required: "Please enter your Full Name",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Your name needs to be at least {0} characters")
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid Email Address",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid Email Address"
        },
        telephone: {
            required: "Please enter a valid Telephone Number",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid Telephone Number"
        },
        message: {
            required: "You need to enter details!",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("checked");
    }
});
});


<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['contactform'])) {
  //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
  if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
      $hasError = true;
  } else {
      $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
  }

  //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
  if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
  } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
      $hasError = true;
  } else {
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  }

  //Check to make sure comments were entered
  if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
  } else {
      if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
          $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
      } else {
          $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
      }
  }

  //If there is no error, send the email
  if(!isset($hasError)) {
      $emailTo = 'email address'; //Put your own email address here
      $subject = 'Contact Form';
      $body = "Full Name: $name \nEmail Address: $email \nDetails: $comments";
      $headers = 'From: Company <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

      mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
      $emailSent = true;
      die(header('Location: index.html'));
  }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Use the `placeholder` attribute instead of putting the default in the input field. For compatibility with older browsers, there are jQuery placeholder plugins.

Comment: That's great Mike.

The only problem I'm having is I've used the placeholders and the Jquery plugin for other browsers, however I'm having an issue whereby the placeholder does not disappear in IE if I submit the form and validation returns errors.

As a result the placeholder stays in the background of the field and the text is written over the top which is hard to read.

Comment: @user2040455: Modernizr + this snippet (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text) work well in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeholder` attribute instead of putting the default values in the field.

```
<input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" placeholder="Full Name" />
```

Then, to enable placeholders in IE, use the following plugin:

```
// ****** START jQuery Placeholder INTEGRATION ***** //

/* Adds class="placeholder" to input elements in browsers that do not support native placeholder attributes (such as IE 6-9) 
http://mths.be/placeholder v2.0.7 by @mathias
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder
 */
;(function(f,h,$){var a='placeholder' in h.createElement('input'),d='placeholder' in h.createElement('textarea'),i=$.fn,c=$.valHooks,k,j;if(a&&d){j=i.placeholder=function(){return this};j.input=j.textarea=true}else{j=i.placeholder=function(){var l=this;l.filter((a?'textarea':':input')+'[placeholder]').not('.placeholder').bind({'focus.placeholder':b,'blur.placeholder':e}).data('placeholder-enabled',true).trigger('blur.placeholder');return l};j.input=a;j.textarea=d;k={get:function(m){var l=$(m);return l.data('placeholder-enabled')&&l.hasClass('placeholder')?'':m.value},set:function(m,n){var l=$(m);if(!l.data('placeholder-enabled')){return m.value=n}if(n==''){m.value=n;if(m!=h.activeElement){e.call(m)}}else{if(l.hasClass('placeholder')){b.call(m,true,n)||(m.value=n)}else{m.value=n}}return l}};a||(c.input=k);d||(c.textarea=k);$(function(){$(h).delegate('form','submit.placeholder',function(){var l=$('.placeholder',this).each(b);setTimeout(function(){l.each(e)},10)})});$(f).bind('beforeunload.placeholder',function(){$('.placeholder').each(function(){this.value=''})})}function g(m){var l={},n=/^jQuery\d+$/;$.each(m.attributes,function(p,o){if(o.specified&&!n.test(o.name)){l[o.name]=o.value}});return l}function b(m,n){var l=this,o=$(l);if(l.value==o.attr('placeholder')&&o.hasClass('placeholder')){if(o.data('placeholder-password')){o=o.hide().next().show().attr('id',o.removeAttr('id').data('placeholder-id'));if(m===true){return o[0].value=n}o.focus()}else{l.value='';o.removeClass('placeholder');l==h.activeElement&&l.select()}}}function e(){var q,l=this,p=$(l),m=p,o=this.id;if(l.value==''){if(l.type=='password'){if(!p.data('placeholder-textinput')){try{q=p.clone().attr({type:'text'})}catch(n){q=$('<input>').attr($.extend(g(this),{type:'text'}))}q.removeAttr('name').data({'placeholder-password':true,'placeholder-id':o}).bind('focus.placeholder',b);p.data({'placeholder-textinput':q,'placeholder-id':o}).before(q)}p=p.removeAttr('id').hide().prev().attr('id',o).show()}p.addClass('placeholder');p[0].value=p.attr('placeholder')}else{p.removeClass('placeholder')}}}(this,document,jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
});

// ****** END jQuery Placeholder INTEGRATION ***** //
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle with IE placeholder integration: http://jsfiddle.net/DNX8V/1/

Validation seems to be working fine to me...?

**UPDATE #2**

Replace the email validation with this:

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

Then

```
if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

Comment: I've used the /*! http://mths.be/placeholder v2.0.7 by @mathias */ placeholder plugin. The placeholder is working but the fields with the values in aren't being validated now as there's a value in there. It validates perfectly in FF but not in IE.

Comment: Instead of using `if(!isset($hasError)) {`, use `if($hasError === true)) {`

Comment: The PHP side of it works perfectly it's just the JS validation that's the issue.

Comment: Check the fiddle in my updated answer. Am I missing something? It appears to be working to me.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't seem to be working in IE. I opened your fiddle link in IE and it just showed a blank field with a submit button :|

Comment: I didn't include the placeholder plugin with the fiddle. I think you need to read up on the documentation for JSvalidate or whatever plugin you are using for validation. The fiddle works fine for me, so it's obviously an issue with your particular browser. Someone else check the fiddle.

Comment: I don't know what it is but the fields just aren't being validated in IE with the placeholder. It's treating it as if there is a value there and therefore submitting with the value as "Full Name". The only field that is coming back as wrong is Email Address, which is saying that it is in the incorrect format.
Would it help if I linked you to the website in question?

Comment: You can put a link to the site, but the way the placeholder plugin works is that in IE, it places the value of the `placeholder` attribute as the value of the text field. If it's just the email field, you could remove validation for that field and replace it with the JS in UPDATE #2 of my answer.

Comment: The php form is working perfectly. The javascript is working exactly the way I want apart from validating the default field. Is there no JS I can add to the existing for it to basically regard the default value as blank or something like that?

Comment: Can anybody give any further help?